# Is there a way to configure openapi-generator to use jakarta package during generation

Tags: java, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I've recently upgraded my project to use spring-boot 3.0.0. So I don't have `javax.*` modules in the project anymore. But the Open API generator keeps trying to import `javax` modules. Especially, it uses `javax.annotation.Generated` for the `@Generated` annotation which is not present in the project anymore. Is there a way to reconfigure it somehow?

Comment: The generator documentation page (https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators) is always the first goto in these cases. OpenAPI tech  is well adapted and chances are, the community has already hit the issue and delivered the fix

Comment: @SANJAYGAUTAM see sashok_bg's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743432/2886891 - it works with `<configOptions> <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe> </configOptions>` since some version. I am using it and I can confirm that it works. In my opinion this should be the accepted answer. The `useSpringBoot3` answer with the most votes works only for server-side generator `spring`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should follow the documentation whenever possible.

The property that you need is either "useSpringBoot3" or "useJakartaEe"

1. Go to https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin
2. At the end of the table you see "configHelp" property which will give you configs for the current generator "spring" in my case
3. Rerun "mvn clean install" - this will give you a list of available "configOptions".
4. Read the list and found a property

   useJakartaEe:
   whether to use Jakarta EE namespace instead of javax (Default: false)

My final pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <configHelp>false</configHelp>
                <configOptions>
                    <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                </configOptions>
                <inputSpec>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.openapi.yaml
                </inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>some.package</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>some.package.model</modelPackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Cheers

Comment: using the setting ```<useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>``` gives me the error ```package jakarta.annotation does not exist```. What am I doing wrong? Here is the pom snippet: https://pastebin.com/KGvwFauv

Comment: @ArthurEirich do you have the correct Jakarta dependency versions? I had a similar error, it turned out I forgot to include jakarta.annotation-api in a version which actually uses the new jakarta.annotation package name 

Comment: I had all the needed dependencies. My problem was the option `<globalProperties<skipFormModel>false</skipFormModel></globalProperties>` not being set. After I scrolled trhough the log I saw a warning that a model class wasnt generated. Googled the log message for it and found a github bug

Comment: @DonHo https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10415 and https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/12036 are those bugs where I found out about the option

Answer (score 42):

Yes, you can use useSpringBoot3: "true" in your configoptions of the generator.
Example in gradle:

```
        configOptions = [
            useSpringBoot3: "true"
        ]
```

Comment: For some weird reason, this option works only for the SPRING generator https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/, which generates the server.

Comment: The top option only works for the `Spring` generator. 

If you are generating code for the client like `Java` generator, this option is not available. Currently I don't see any option to allow Jakarta migration.

Comment: Its still an open issue : https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/13124

Comment: It seems that setting `useJakartaEe: 'true'` should work in the `java` generator since openapi-generator 6.3.0, but apparently some configurations are not working well, and thus the issue is still open.

It works well for me using the `native` library!

Answer (score 1):

I use `openapi-generator generate` command and adding options that

```
--additional-properties=useSpringBoot3=true
```

also worked.
Here is the reference: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/

Comment: This is virtually the same, and **has the same issues** as Shaki's answer from 28.11.2022: it only works for the *server-side* Spring generator. If you are generating code for the *client-side* Java generator, you need to use `useJakartaEe=true` as in the sashok_bg's now-accepted answer.