# Openapi generator maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator, java-17

I would like to try and use Openapi generator maven plugin with Spring Boot project.

Only example I can find by Googling is from Baeldung. But it simply is not possible to figure out the setup from that example. Example project is part of probably more than 1000 project chain dependencies ...

I know that this is not the forum for this kind of question, but this time only :) could someone point me to an example that demonstrates who to use the plugin with Spring Boot and java 17.

I get errorrs like

```
package javax.servlet.http does not exist
```

My latest current POM trial :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                /Users/ok/dev/openapi/demo/src/main/resources/petstore.yaml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.demo.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.demo.model</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
<!--
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            </configOptions>
-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Please, Try mine

- recent
- *pom only* ([swagger plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin), not [open-api's](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin) ... it was no "taste decision", but just what i had recently;)
- *openapi-v3*
- sample yaml/json is from petstore.swagger (links below)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-codegen-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>swagger-codegen-spring</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId> <--! v3 -->
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.42</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- prints (only, additionally) language specific(!) "config options help" -->
            <id>api-generate-help</id> 
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
              <!-- language/generator!! -->
              <language>spring</language>
              <configHelp>true</configHelp>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <!-- this is the generation: -->
          <execution>
            <id>api-generate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <!-- input api definition -->
              <inputSpec>src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
              <!-- language/generator!! -->
              <language>spring</language>
              <!-- output folder -->
              <output>${project.build.directory}/gen</output>
              <!-- ... -->
              <configOptions> <!-- these are language specific: -->
                <interfaceOnly>false</interfaceOnly>
                <java8>false</java8>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <!--sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder-->
                <throwsException>true</throwsException>
                <useTags>true</useTags>
                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

After:

```bash
mvn generate-sources 
# or idempotent e.g. package, install, ...
```

We get a "generated project" in (the configured) `target/gen` folder.

This project is:

- *very* language/generator specific
- *independent* from the "parent" and has it's own pom (usually)
- i would *not* mix it into (root) directory of an existing pom

#### API definition links:

- https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json
- https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.yaml
- https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
- https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml

#### Stay up-to-date

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin (master/v2)
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin (v3 branch)

And to be fair, also the "concurrence":

- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Also "works":

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.5.0</version> <!-- latest -->
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <inputSpec>
          https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.yaml
        </inputSpec>
        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
        <output>${project.build.directory}/gen-openapi</output>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you *want* to mix api generation *into existing* codebase, i am out! ;p

Comment: after testing and "diff"ing, as of today, i would recommend openapi plugin! 1. it uses (already) springdoc (in opposite to springfox) 2. it accepts url/remote `langugaeSpec` (swagger plugin "prefers" the local ones(throws exception)) ...

Answer (score 4):

Use this property to solve this:

useJakartaEe: "true"

Comment: This did the trick!
compare with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743432/4994931

Comment: This should be an accepted answer! Along with useSpringBoot3: "true" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76858939/410439)

you need to make `generateSupportingFiles` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

- generateSupportingFiles to true

And you will find a generated pom.xml in targets. Check it, it contains all the dependencies you need; put what you need in your main pom.xml.